# How is updateInteractiveTransition: implemented?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning `UIViewController` transition animation. When i read the  `updateInteractiveTransition(_:)` method of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`,  i get very confused.

The Apple documentation says:

> This is a convenience method that calls through to
>   the updateInteractiveTransition: method of the context object.

Yeah, context object did have a `updateInteractiveTransition:` method. But `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` doesn't have a property pointing to a context object.

So how `updateInteractiveTransition:` is implemented in `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` and how is`UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` able to call method of context object since it doesn't have pointer pointing to a`UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` object? Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at its assembly and stepping through,

`-[UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition updateInteractiveTransition:]` calls

`+[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _associatedTransitionContextForObject:self]` to get the `transitionContext` object,
where `self` is the instance of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

This internally calls `objc_getAssociatedObject(interactor, _UIAssociatedTransitionContextKey)`.

now, as for when it gets stored, it gets stored when `-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _setInteractor:]` is invoked by `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]` which receives both the animator and interactor from the transitioningDelegate.

one of the thing that `_setInteractor:` does is `objc_setAssociatedObject(interactor, _UIAssociatedTransitionContextKey, ...)`.